# Scheduled stop of maintenance task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I need something to automatically stop my index maintenance job on Saturday night. How do I do that? How can I check automatically if my index maintenance job is still running and if it's running, stop it every Saturday night before 12 am?

Right now I do it manually using:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job
N'The name of the job'
```

How can I automate stopping the job at a certain time ?

Comment: You just schedule the first block of T-SQL that was in the code on this question and answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157712/declare-variable-to-hold-job-name-and-if-job-running-kill-it/157723#157723

Comment: Well just put your stop statement as you are already using,  into a job that runs an 12am on Saturday. If the reindex job has already finished you will get an error message, which you could set to successfully quit the stop job and if the job is still running you will get a successful return value anyway. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, you can use `DATEName(DW, GETDATE())` to see if it is *Saturday* along with time and then have your `sp_stop_job` run to stop the job.

You can put that code in `IF` .. check saturday and time then run stop job code else exit gracefully.

It would be much better if you use [Ola's Index maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) (or Minnionware - I have not used it though, since I am using the former).

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'ALL_DATABASES', 
        @FragmentationLow = NULL,
        @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE',
        @FragmentationHigh =  'INDEX_REORGANIZE',
        @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
        @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
        @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
        @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y',
        @TimeLimit = 5400, -- 90 minutes, specified in seconds
        @LogToTable = 'Y',
        @Indexes = 'ALL_INDEXES',
        @SortInTempdb = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a quick way to do this is you create a monitoring job that is **scheduled to run every Saturday at 12:00am**, and in this monitoring job, you only need one step as follows:

```
use msdb
declare @index_jobname varchar(255) = '<your index job name>';
if exists(
select a.* from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a
inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
on a.job_id = j.job_id
and j.name = @index_jobname
and a.stop_execution_date is null
)
begin
    print 'index maint job is stopped';
    exec sp_stop_job @job_name=@index_jobname;
end
```